# What is the MSVC __asm keyword for GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I was writing a code in asm inside a C program, and I misread that __asm{...} was what i needed to be able to do that. I later found out that __asm is for MSVC compiler, not GCC. What is the equivalent in C for MSVC's __asm keyword? I have labels and loops in the code I wrote and don't know how what's the syntax for them in whatever the __asm keyword is for GCC.

My code is doing (or trying to do) the ancient multiplication method.

```
int p = 0;
int b = 10;
int a  = 5;
/*
while(b!= 0){
    if(b%2 != 0) p+=a;
    a+=a;
    b/=2;
}
printf("%i\n",p);
*/



__asm{
    mov p, 0
    mov edx, p
    mov ebx, a
    mov ax,b
    jmp checkend

notEven:
    add edx, ebx
    mov edx, a  


checkend:
    cmp b, 0
    je endok


    test ax, 1
    jnz notEven

    add ebx, ebx
    mov a, ebx
    mov dx, 0
    mov ax, b
    mov bx, 2
    div bx
    mov b,ax
}
printf("%i\n",p);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `__asm` is neither C++ nor C. It's a compiler specific keyword (not a function). There is no standard method for including inline assembler code. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: `__asm` is an MSVC keyword for both C and C++, though it is only valid for x86-32 projects. GCC has a different syntax for inline assembly. I believe you can find more documentation for it [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I'm using GCC.

Comment: For gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

Comment: My personal recommendation is that you ditch inline assembly and put your assembly code in a normal assembly file instead.  Inline assembly is difficult to get right and causes all sorts of weird problems you don't want to deal with, especially if you are a beginner.

Comment: Just to add my voice to what @fuz said about not using inline asm.  It can be cool, it can be interesting, it can be educational.  But you could write a page *full* of [reasons not to use inline asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm).  Indeed, the very fact that you have to re-write this code now is one of them (#4).

Comment: I'm kind of a newbie to C too. How can I call an assembly object from C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the equivalent in C for C++'s `__asm` function?

C has no standard provision for inline assembly, so it depends on your implementation.  The standard documents an `asm` keyword as a *common extension*, but whether that is available and what its semantics may be depends on your C implementation.

Since you've tagged GCC, you would want to consult [GCC's documentation on inline assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html).  GCC does use the `asm` keyword for this.  The most bare-bones usage takes this form:

```
asm ( AssemblerInstructions ... );
```

Comment: It should be noted that GCC basic asm will not suffice here unless you want to violate the warnings in the GCC documentation and run amok of undefined behaviour. You'll have to use GCC's extended inline assembly for the code the OP presented. Alternatively (and easier to understand) is to put the assembly code in a separate assembly object and call it from _C_. (you just then need to deal with the calling convention and not be concerned about the nuances of GCC's inline assembly which can be very troublesome and finicky.

Comment: I'm kind of a newbie to C too. How can I call an assembly object from C?